# Creating a dictionary for tabular data in Julia

Tags: dictionary, julia

I have a tabular data like:

```
+---+----+----+
|   | a  | b  |
+---+----+----+
| P |  1 |  2 |
| Q | 10 | 20 |
+---+----+----+
```

and I want to represent this using a `Dict`.

With the column and row names:

```
x = ["a", "b"]
y = ["P", "Q"]
```

and data

```
data = [ 1  2 ;
        10 20  ]
```

how may I create a dictionary object `d`, so that `d["a", "P"] = 1` and so on? Is there a way like

```
d = Dict(zip(x,y,data))
```

?

Comment: NamedArrays (link: https://github.com/davidavdav/NamedArrays.jl) might be doing what you want in terms of indexing and more.

Answer (score 4):

Your code works with a minor change to use `Iterators.product`:

```
d = Dict(zip(Iterators.product(x, y), data.'))
```

To do this you need to add a line `using Iterators` to your project, and might need to `Pkg.add("Iterators")`. Because Julia matrices are column-major (elements are stored in order within columns, and columns are stored in order within the matrix), we needed to transpose the `data` matrix using the transpose operator `.'`.

This is a literal answer to your question. I don't recommend doing that. If you have tabular data, it's probably better to use a [DataFrame](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl). These are not two dimensional (rows have no names) but that can be fixed by adding an additional column, and using `select`.